# TTS テキスト読み上げ機能をmonacaで実装する方法

Tags: monaca, cordova

こんにちは。monacaでTTS(text-to-speech)が実装出来ますでしょうか？
Web Speech APIを入れたところ、chromeでのIDEプレビューでは読み上げをしてくれるのですが、デバッガーやビルドしたアプリだとiOSもAndroidもダメでした。

開発中のアプリは単語学習アプリで、読み上げ字数は少ないのですが、単語が何千もあります。mp3での`<audio>`タグによる再生も容量の問題で、別の方法を模索しております。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

[Cordova Text-to-Speech Plugin](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts)が使えます。

初めて読み上げる言語の場合は読み上げ音声データのダウンロード・インストールが発生します。

```
// 日本語の読み上げ例
// Androidで確認しています
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function (){
    document.getElementById("speech").addEventListener('click', function(){
        TTS.speak({
            text: 'こんにちは、声の世界。',
            locale: 'ja-JP',
            rate: 1,
        }, function () {
            alert('success');
        }, function (reason) {
            alert(reason);
        });
    });
}, false);
```